# The postioning at the bottom right corner using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to position the dialogue box at the bottom right corner of the page, but I was unsuccessful.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();

    {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

  });
</script>​
```

Comment: Why you put the CSS code block in jQuery? Please give some clean code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/eNaOjN). You can add a position (see the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)) to a dialog. This is the full jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "right bottom"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Work perfectly. Very much appreciated.  if I want to use it for other popup windows, for example creating a form, what would be the code, any comment?

Comment: @user200 What do you mean? You can position the any dialog wherever you want.

Comment: When I create a form instead of a dialogue box, I got the codes instaed of the popup window. is that make sense?

Comment: @user200 When you're creating a form, it will be with html tags? You can position it with pure css.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example code, I really appreciate it. Because I  did it but it did not work for me. I have used HTML and CSS codes

Comment: You better create a new question when you're stuck. Another question in this topic might be confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) to apply the CSS rules.

```js
$(function() {
  // $('#dialog').dialog();
  $("#dialog").css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'bottom': 0,
    'right': 0
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('//placehold.it/100x100');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

---

But there shouldn't be any reason to use jQuery to do this, as it is completely possible with CSS alone.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('//placehold.it/100x100');
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog"></div>
```